# Simple code password retry

Tags: vba, password-protection

I am a beginner and I have spent hours in Google but no one has the answer.

To test for error write two any password to cause an error – It works OK the first time (Strike 1), but it fails on the second bad password.  It’s driving me bananas!  I tried to reset the error counter??? – Nothing works for me!!!

I have a workbook open with a routine on “ThisWorkbook” with a call (Branch) to “Sub Password_Check” on Module 9. I am an old Fortran programer but VBA is by far more complicated!

```
    Sub Password_Check()
    Dim i As Integer
    iTotal = 0
    On Error GoTo Message
    For i = 1 To 3
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Message:
    If i = 1 Then MsgBox "          STRIKE " & (i)
    If i = 2 Then MsgBox "          STRIKE " & (i)
    If i = 3 Then MsgBox "          STRIKE " & (i)
    Next
    Application.Quit
    End Sub
```

I will be very grateful!

Regards,

Oscar G Duarte

Thank you in advance for all your help!!!

Comment: You had me at Fortran! So what is `Password_Check` supposed to do, and what is the significance of the 3 strikes? As far as I can tell, there is never a check to see if the password was entered correctly or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is inside the for loop. You want to give the user three tries to unlock a workbook. You need to have the error handler outside of the loop. I'm not a VBA programmer or windows user so I have no way to test this but your logic needs to look something more like this. Hopefully it helps. Look into error handling and subroutines within the context of VBA.

```
Sub Password_Check() 
    Dim i As Integer
    iTotal = 0 
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler 
    For i = 1 To 3 
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect 
    Next

    Exit Sub

    ErrorHandler: 
        MsgBox " STRIKE " & (i)
        if i = 3 Then 
            Application.Quit
        Else
            Resume

End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheet.Unprotect()` has some interesting behavior that makes this solution not work as intended.